# Prettier not working on save from within Visual Studio Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, prettier

It appears the formatting via keyboard and formatting from the menu are not on the same page, but I don't know why. Below are my exact detailed steps...

##### From Visual Studio Code 1.75.1

- I installed the extension `Prettier - Code formatter` v9.10.4
- From File -> Preferences -> Settings, I typed in `default format` and set it to Prettier - Code format

[image]

- Again from File -> Preferences -> Settings, I typed in `format on save` and checked the box.

[image]

Now from within my ReactJs project workspace, I have the following file with code example:

```js
import React from "react";

import ChartBar from "./ChartBar";
import "./Chart.css";

const Chart = (props) => {
  return <div><div> do something </div><div> do something </div><div> do something </div></div>;
};

export default Chart;
```

When I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, it doesn't change anything.

But if I right click on the window and select `Format Document with`, and select `Prettier Code Formatter` it corrects the format to the following...

```js
import React from "react";

import ChartBar from "./ChartBar";
import "./Chart.css";

const Chart = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div> do something </div>
      <div> do something </div>
      <div> do something </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chart;
```

Also, from within my workspace, I generated a .vscode folder with a settings.json file, with the following settings...

```json
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
}
```

Still no fix.

Why can't I get my Format on Save to work exactly as clicking on the menu option???

**Update**

I finally figured it out. In addition to my settings above, I also needed to updated my workspace settings.json file with the following code:

```js
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  }
}
```

All good now!

Comment: Just a hint, make sure that your `javascript`/`typescript` formatter is set to `esbenp.prettier-vscode`, in your `settings.json`.

Comment: nothing with that.

Comment: Can you include your `settings.json`  as a snippet?

Comment: Its noted in my original post.

Comment: I meant the one with all your options. `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `P`, write `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)` and hit enter, which will open up your user settings as json.

Comment: I got it!  thank you - I was slightly off in my workspace settins.json file.  I needed the "exact" default formatter example they have for us in their extension page in vscode.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VSCode, hit `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `P`, write `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)` and hit enter, it will open up your `settings.json`:

Make sure `prettier` is your default formatter:

```json
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
```

you can set it for specific languages e.g: for `typescript`:

```json
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
```

Comment: I had this set up for typescriptreact, but not typescript. Great save. Thank you!